# Why the spotlight is turned off no light is coming out?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have in the scene in the `Hierarchy Directional Light` added automatic when creating new project. And then I added also a `spotlight`.

I didn't change or disabled the spotlight just added it to the hierarchy: GameObject > Light > Spotlight

But even if the scene is dark or not the spotlight is like turned off.

[image: Spot]

Then I went in the editor to the menu to: `Window > Lighting > Settings`
Not sure 100% what I did but I changed the 
`Skybox Material` to `FrameDebuggerRenderTargetDisplay`.

Then I changed the `Albedo Boost` by one value and it made it all dark black.
In the end I got this dark/black scene and still the spotlight is turned off.

My main goal is to make everything black/dark and use the spotlight to light on specific place/area.
But not sure if making this scene dark is the right way and not sure why the `spotlight` is not showing light at all.

I have on the scene some spheres and a character I want to `spotlight` on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are can be different issues.

Intensity is not high.

1. Your **player quality settings** are not set to fantastic, check it change it(see below image
   [image]
2. Your light button may not active in scene (See below image). At the top of the **scene view is a button that toggles scene lighting**, activate it and you should get the correct lighting.

[image]

3. or your **light culling mask** set to nothing

Comment: I think i found it. Once changed the Range of the spotlight to 25 it's showing the light.

Comment: can you please tell us what what was the problem?